# Malsup plugin submit only works the first time in IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Newbie to mvc / .net web development

I'm using MVC3 and the Malsup JQuery form plugin on a partial view ...

On form submit button I execute the following script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#frm_Attachments').submit(function (e) {

         e.preventDefault(); 
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();

         var ajaxSubmitOptions = {
             target: $("#Attachment_Div") 
         };

         $(this).ajaxSubmit(ajaxSubmitOptions);

         return false; 

     });
 });
```

All works great in Firefox and Chrome ... but not in IE9.  The issue is that in IE the submit only works the first time, after that nothing happens when I click the submit button.

Controller below

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Partial_Qual_Attachments(Teacher_Application.Qualification_Attachment model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (model.Save(file)) // all ok
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Data successfully saved";
        }
        else // error
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Unable to save data, please try again or contact the system administrator";
        }

       model = new Teacher_Application.Qualification_Attachment(SessionData.Selected_Teacher_ID);

        ModelState.Clear();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is there any js error thrown while processing the ajax response?

Comment: Sorry, misread your reply at 1st ... it seems to simply do nothing i.e. I put an alert() after the frm_attachments.submit and it fires only the 1st time ... so it does not even get to the submit/processing

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  To do with event binding after ajax.  Thanks.